# Icons on Git Files in local machine

Tags: macos, git, version-control, github, tortoisesvn

I am coming from SVN world! and with Tortoise SVN if I was looking at my folders and files they had small icons like a green check mark, a blue plus sign, etc so I could visually see what is changed,etc...But I can't see that visual thing for Git, I installed GitHub for Mac from here:http://mac.github.com
Is there any other thing I should install ? or any better software recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

The GitHub client seems to be made to interact with, well, github.com !

Have a look at that other question, multiple fine OS X clients are mentioned :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158650/easy-to-use-git-client-for-non-technical-people

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative answer, try from the command line. `git status`. Then hit up arrow to do it again next time. There are many reasons to use git from the command line:

- history
- piping
- tab completion
- scripts
- speed